# How to find the number of joins behind SQL execution - Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I'm working on a SQL query which has 110+ joins and with Oracle 12C, getting below error when running the query.

ORA-01792: maximum number of columns in a table or view is 1000
01792. 00000 -  "maximum number of columns in a table or view is 1000"

Received a patch from oracle and due to some reason unable to apply patch on servers. I have couple of questions.

1. What is the best way to refactor/split this large query
2. Is there a way to find the number of columns being joined when query runs. Wanted to know whether my changes to sql making some difference in reducing the number of joins.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Depends on where the number of columns becomes a problem. What is the total number of columns returned by the query? Are there any sub-queries, especially sub-queries that could be instantiated in a temporary table (like for a sort operation) that could have more than 1000 columns? What's the execution plan of your query? It's hard to say without seeing the code involved and the execution plan (aka explain plan).

Comment: As far as I understand, your problem isn't 100+ **joins**, but number of **columns** query produces. If you use it as CTAS (Create Table As Select) or something like that, and you used `select * from 110+ joins` and `*` evaluates to more than 1000 columns, then you should substitute `*` with actual column list, paying attention to number of columns as it can't exceed 1000. By the way, who/what is capable of viewing 1000 columns at a time? Looks like a design flaw (?).

Comment: This is the design in existing application(pretty old) and don't have an option to change the design. It is selecting only the specific columns (around 1500 columns not *) after too many joins. Problem here is with too many joins that creates more than 1000 columns behind the scene.